# How to make the data studs always appear on a classic Google Line Chart

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I have to use classic Google Line Chart because the Material version doesn't support the curved lines yet, but I like curves. Unfortunately though it seems that only Material chart displays the datum stems (I'm not sure if I describe that properly, but I mean those dots which represent the data points on the line), and only when you hover over a line (anywhere along the line).

Here is a screenshot, to the left is a Google Material Chart and I'm hovering over the line, to the right is a chartjs chart, shows the studs even without hovering over anything.
[image: screenshot of data studs]

Google Line Chart JSFiddle where you can see how the Material and the Classic Google Charts behave: https://jsfiddle.net/csabatoth/yyhLwkaf/

```
var classicOptions = {
    title: 'Foo',
    width: 900,
    height: 500,
    theme: 'material',
    curveType: 'function'
    // TODO
};
```

When in Material mode, you have to hover over a line to cause the data studs to appear. Classic charts is even worse in this respect: you have to "follow" the line until you hit a data point, and that's when it is only revealed.

What I desire is something like that (see the first visible line chart):
http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#line-chart-introduction
The data studs are visible regardless you hover over the line or not. I cannot seem to find out which is the proper option for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for `pointSize`

```js
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['line', 'corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

  var button = document.getElementById('change-chart');
  var chartDiv = document.getElementById('chart_div');

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('date', 'Month');
  data.addColumn('number', "Average Temperature");
  data.addColumn('number', "Average Hours of Daylight");

  data.addRows([
    [new Date(2014, 0),  -.5,  5.7],
    [new Date(2014, 1),   .4,  8.7],
    [new Date(2014, 2),   .5,   12],
    [new Date(2014, 3),  2.9, 15.3],
    [new Date(2014, 4),  6.3, 18.6],
    [new Date(2014, 5),    9, 20.9],
    [new Date(2014, 6), 10.6, 19.8],
    [new Date(2014, 7), 10.3, 16.6],
    [new Date(2014, 8),  7.4, 13.3],
    [new Date(2014, 9),  4.4,  9.9],
    [new Date(2014, 10), 1.1,  6.6],
    [new Date(2014, 11), -.2,  4.5]
  ]);

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([0, 1, 2]);


  var materialOptions = {
    chart: {
      title: 'Average Temperatures and Daylight in Iceland Throughout the Year'
    },
    width: 900,
    height: 500,
    series: {
      // Gives each series an axis name that matches the Y-axis below.
      0: {axis: 'Temps'},
      1: {axis: 'Daylight'}
    },
    axes: {
      // Adds labels to each axis; they don't have to match the axis names.
      y: {
        Temps: {label: 'Temps (Celsius)'},
        Daylight: {label: 'Daylight'}
      }
    }
  };

  var classicOptions = {
    curveType: 'function',
    pointSize: 10,
    title: 'Average Temperatures and Daylight in Iceland Throughout the Year',
    width: 900,
    height: 500,
    // Gives each series an axis that matches the vAxes number below.
    series: {
      0: {targetAxisIndex: 0},
      1: {targetAxisIndex: 1}
    },
    vAxes: {
      // Adds titles to each axis.
      0: {title: 'Temps (Celsius)'},
      1: {title: 'Daylight'}
    },
    hAxis: {
      ticks: [
              new Date(2014, 0), new Date(2014, 1), new Date(2014, 2), new Date(2014, 3),
              new Date(2014, 4),  new Date(2014, 5), new Date(2014, 6), new Date(2014, 7),
              new Date(2014, 8), new Date(2014, 9), new Date(2014, 10), new Date(2014, 11)
             ]
    },
    vAxis: {
      viewWindow: {
        max: 30
      }
    }
  };

  function drawMaterialChart() {
    var materialChart = new google.charts.Line(chartDiv);
    materialChart.draw(view, materialOptions);
    button.innerText = 'Change to Classic';
    button.onclick = drawClassicChart;
  }

  function drawClassicChart() {
    var classicChart = new google.visualization.LineChart(chartDiv);
    classicChart.draw(view, classicOptions);
    button.innerText = 'Change to Material';
    button.onclick = drawMaterialChart;
  }

  drawClassicChart();

}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<button id="change-chart">Change to Material</button>
<br><br>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: I didn't mean the annotations. I added a screenshot to help. What I only want is to have the dots displayed on the line always, just like the default behavior of chartjs. Otherwise if you switch a line chart to be curved you kinda have to sweep on the curve to find the actual data point.

Comment: see this too --> [Customizing Points](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/points)

Comment: That's stunning how you can even customize points. I'd be happy to see more and more features with material charts.